# Using <form> tag

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a form like so:

```html
<form action="" method="get" id="contact_form">

  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="Navn" value="">

  <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" placeholder="Telefonnummer" value="">

  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" value="">

  <textarea cols="1" rows="1" name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Besked"></textarea>
    
  <button>Submit</button>
  <img src="" alt="" class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw loader"/>

</form>
```

using a javascript file to validate the input areas as well as handling the redirect to the following php file:

```html
<?php

$errorMSG = "";

// NAME
if (empty($_POST["firstname"])) {
    $errorMSG = "Name is required ";
} else {
    $name = $_POST["firstname"];
}

if (empty($_POST["telephone"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Telephone is required ";
} else {
    $telephone = $_POST["telephone"];
}

// EMAIL
if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Email is required ";
} else {
    $email = $_POST["email"];
}

// MESSAGE
if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Message is required ";
} else {
    $comment = $_POST["comment"];
}


$EmailTo = "EMAIL@EMAIL.com";
$Subject = "New Message Received";

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Telephone: ";
$Body .= $telephone;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email);
```

Since it isn't possible to use the `<form>` tag on a masterpage file, how does one go about adding a form?

Tried using: https://sharepointformsubmit.codeplex.com/ which didn't do anything unfortunately. Is it possible to create a web part page and paste the form into that and then linking to it on the masterpage? If so, anything one needs to be aware of when it comes to the javascript file?

Comment: It seems exceedingly odd to be mingling PHP with SharePoint. Is there a reason you're avoiding using a SharePoint list to collect this information?

Comment: This is being migrated from a standard host to Sharepoint. I'll have a look at lists, thanks.